# non breaking space in new rte (ck_editor)

Tags: typo3

I use TYPO3 LTS, last version. My problem occurs in the new RTE ck_editor. In short: i get non breaking space characters when i put a list in a table cell. The result in the frontend looks like this:

```
<td>&nbsp;<ul><li>text</li></ul></td>
```

In the TYPO3 backend all is correct: no non breaking space, either in the edit window of the RTE, nor in the code view of the RTE. I checked the database table but there is also no non breaking space.

Therefore it seems to to happen during the frontend rendering in TYPO3.

Any ideas how i can fix it?

Thanks!
Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've run into this issue: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/83795

The latest comment suggests to use this TSConfig:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.innerStdWrap_all.ifBlank >
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.innerStdWrap_all.ifBlank =
```

Could you tell us if it works for you? Please, may I ask you to update that issue? (Also, if you find some drawbacks). Thank you!

Comment: Thats it, many thanks!! I dont see any difficulties this moment but the site is still in development, so no heavy RTE work. I left a comment in forge - when i run into problems i will tell it in forge too.

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you for your feedback and happy work.